# Can't load "props" data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my project, I download data from the following page (with the help of Axios):

> http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=init_data_for_index

The data is used in my main page.

After that, I try to pass these data through "props" to my center content components.

My Vue debugger shows me that it has been done right:

[image: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/09/06/0023/2790/1571558/58/7a088dbe86.jpg]

But in into my center content component, I can't get this data to show it into my HTML code.

I could get part of the data like this: `dbIndex.data`

But if I try to get this props data deeper like this: `dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index`

The following error is displayed:

> Cannot read property 'init_data_for_index' of undefined.

#### My question is:

How should I get this data correctly in my case?

```js
import LiServiceApp from '~/components/CenterContentIndexApp/LiServiceApp';
  export default {
    props: ['dbIndex'],
    components: {
      LiServiceApp,
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
 <section class="center_content_index">
    <ul class="ul_1">
        <li class="li_3">
          {{  dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index  }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!--  <ul class="ul_1"> end -->
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Can show a snippet from your Parent Component?

Comment: It sounds like an asynchronous problem. Your component is trying to render before `dbIndex.data` is populated by your axios call, so `dbIndex.data` is undefined. You could try a computed property called `dataForIndex` that checks `if (!dbIndex.data) { return null } return dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index; }` and just return the name of the computed property instead of the prop direectly in your template

Comment: Or another solution would be to not render the component until the data is loaded with a `v-if`. For example, when you do your axios call, after assigning the data response to your Vue instance, you can set the property `loaded` to false after the promise is resolved. That will make less computed properties for every time you need this prop in your component.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mike_kharkov/v2fn8cz6/4/
that is my parent component.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/qmheouwp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<li class="li_3">
  {{ init_data_for_index }}
</li>


...


computed() {

  init_data_for_index() {
    return this.dbIndex && this.dbIndex.data && this.dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index
      ? this.dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index
      : [];
  },

},
```

So initially `init_data_for_index` is an empty array until it populated from API.